# std::vector resize vs reserve during fread

Tags: c++, vector, resize, fread

This is my working code:

```
size_t FileReader::Read(ByteVector& output)
{
    output.resize(m_elementSize * m_blockSize);
    size_t read = fread(&output[0], m_elementSize, m_blockSize, m_file);
    output.resize(read);
    return read;
}
```

However previous I have tried code which had `output.reserve(m_elementSize * m_blockSize);`

As far as I know `reserve` just founds place in memory for container. `resize` do the same, also changes memory from trash to some given values and change container size.

`fread` first parameter is `void *` and it is the same as `unsigned char *`, my question, why did I get exception while calling `fread`.

Why is it happening? Because `fread` takes void pointer and it do not write into memory using `vector` class.

P.S. forgot to mention `typedef std::vector<unsigned char> ByteVector`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the vector is initially empty, then `output[0]` invokes undefined behaviour (regardless of how much space you have reserved), and on some platforms it may throw an exception.

Comment: Why does it invoke UB?

Comment: If the vector is empty it doesn't have a zeroth element. Attempting to access a non-existent element is UB.

Comment: Not sure, but I think it should always throw an exception, doesn't it?

Comment: Nope. It's equivalent to *(output.begin()), which involves dereferencing a beyond-the-end iterator, which is always undefined behaviour. Throwing an exception is allowed (but then so is anything else) and absolutely nothing is required. You can call `output.at(0)` if you want an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Have found the problem, now I use code I called *working*

I wanted to avoid unnecessary `resize` because it works with data in memory, however after `reserve` `output[0]` do not exists.

What is more after read `vector` size would be zero and `resize` would destroy read data.

Comment: `resize` won't do anything if you pass it the current size of the vector, so your `if` is unnecessary.